# Azure Functions: how to deploy a project downloaded from the Azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have implemented a C# function in the Azure Portal.
I downloaded the content of the Function App as a Visual Studio project.
I now want to deploy it with Azure DevOps release pipeline.
The deployment works fine but my function is not deployed. Sounds like the .csx file is not taken into account.
I tried to change the Build Action of the csx file to C# Compiler but it failed during the compilation with missing dependencies. Not sure it is the right way to proceed.
What are the steps to deploy the Azure functions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little bit overkill to deploy csx functions with AzureDevOps. We could simply zip those files in the same folder structure as they were downloaded, go to `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI` and drag the zip file to deploy. If you prefer command line instead of manual deployment, check [Azure CLI command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#cli).

If you have to work with AzureDevOps, have a look at Build pipeline YAML below(Release pipeline is the default template `Deploy a function app to Azure Functions`).

```
resources:
- repo: self
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
steps:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'

    includeRootFolder: false


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

Note that the `<functionName>.csproj` file downloaded is useless and shouldn't be commited to repo. But if we have installed some extensions and see `extensions.csproj` file, add Net Core build task before ArchiveFiles@2.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'

    arguments: '--configuration release -o bin --no-incremental'
```

Comment: Yes I know that this sounds overkilled to use Azure DevOps, but in our project we have other components to deploy at the same time (Logic Apps, ServiceBus, Log Analytics, ...). It is why we are trying to include the function deployment in the release pipeline.

Comment: @DavidGROSPELIER Totally understand, have added my yaml. Feel free to ask if you are still trapped.